# Android Custom Component Properties

Tags: android, components, widget

I have made an component for Android, which uses two drawables.

Using static values for the drawables in the code, the component works but now I want to declare the values in the properties (XML) does anyone know how to do this?

*Edit;
Is there a way to do this without using the attrs.xml?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say *declaring the values in the properties (XML)*?

Comment: I mean like the standard background attribute, I know it is possible to add attributes/properties like that. Just don't know how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to set up a `res/values/attrs.xml` file to declare the attributes, then go through some code to retrieve those values inside of your `View`'s constructor. I have a [sample here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Views/Meter/) that demonstrates the technique.

Comment: Getting 404 on http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Views/Meter/src/com/commonsware/android/

Comment: Is there a way to do this in code? I don't have direct access to the R.styleable :-(

Comment: Here is another sample: http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/05/02/android-tutorial-42-passing-custom-variables-via-xml-resource-files/

Comment: The Meter view is no longer there, look at https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Views/ColorMixer instead.

Comment: Possible values for the format attribute correspond to the TypedArray getXXX methods (string, boolean etc.) and they can be combined with a pipe | character in attrs.xml.